# After replacing Fragment, Activity still detects Fragment is visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I have one `Activity` that hosts many `Fragments`. In `Fragment A`, I am adding a dialog when the user presses the back button to ask if they are sure if they want to leave this fragment. I added this code in the Activity's `onBackPressed` to control this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentA fragmentA = (FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentA");

    if (fragmentA != null && fragmentA.isVisible()) {
        fragmentA.showExitDialog();
        return;
    }
    else { super.onBackPressed(); }
}
```

And the dialog works perfectly in Fragment A, but when it leaves Fragment A and goes to Fragment B (same activity) with this code:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
                FragmentB.newInstance(), "fragmentB").commit();
```

And I press the back button in Fragment B, it shows the same exit dialog again.

Thus, from my code, it is saying that FragmentA is not null and still visible even after I did the `Replace` function.

**Why is Fragment A still visible when I replaced it with Fragment B?**

Comment: Try to remove and not to replace. And always use commit whatever fragment transaction you apply.

Comment: @icbytes Thanks! This works, but I thought using `replace` was supposed to already do `remove/add` for you? Is it just buggy?

Comment: Do not know. And I also was curios about it until I just accepted it.